# use exceljs stream WorkbookReader/WorkbookWriter to write to read and write the same excel sheet

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I am trying to write to an existing excel file that is very large. which requires me to use the stream WorkbookReader. I am wondering if there is a way to write to this same excel file in an existing sheet? from what I understand if I were to use WorkbookWriter I have to make a new sheet. Here is some code for an example

```
const ExcelJS = require("exceljs");`

const options = {
  sharedStrings: "cache",
  hyperlinks: "ignore",
  worksheets: "emit",
  styles: "ignore",
};
const reader = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookReader("excel/Book1.xlsx", {
  options,
});
async function main() {
  for await (let sheet of reader) {
    for await (let row of sheet) {
      if (row.worksheet.name !== "FieldDef") break;

      if (row.getCell(1).value === 21160) {
        row.getCell(1).value = 21161;
        //row.commit?
        console.log(row.getCell(1).value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```